# Declaring int i outside for-each loop causing error?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {-1,1,1};
    int i;
    for(i: arr){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

above code gives ERROR.
error: bad initializer for for-loop

but the below code works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {-1,1,1};
    for(int i: arr){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Can I know why initializing i outside for-each loop is a mistake.?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: ["Why" questions are very unclear.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/5133585) What *kind* of reasons are you looking for? Would "because the language specification says this is an error" be acceptable to you?

Comment: Because the JLS says so. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: Declaring an int outside a loop doesn't cause any error. What causes your error is completely ignoring the syntax of the for-each loop and just inventing your own (By just removing the type declaration in your for-each loop). You might as well ask why you can't write an if statement as `IF [x ! i]`.... Programming languages have a clearly defined syntax you have to follow. And for the for each statement that means `for(<Type> <variable_name> : <iterable_of_type>)`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by declaring it in the first way? If it were possible, it would expand the scope of the variable unnecessarily, and its value after the loop would be whatever the last element in the array happened to be.

Answer (score 6):

Because you simply can't use for loops like that. The `for in` syntax require you use a new variable which is scoped to the loop. You could use it like this, though:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {-1,1,1};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this isn't _quite_ the same, as in your case `i` is the index, whereas in OP's `i` is the element value.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the enhanced for loop are just like that.

```
for(int x: arr) {
     System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).